# Are a categories objects unique?

Tags: category-theory

The following commutative diagram comes from Awodey's Category theory (p. 4):
[image]

Are objects allowed to appear more than once in a commutative diagram describing a category? From what I understand, the nodes and arrows represent objects and morphisms respectively. Does that mean this category has $4$ objects, two copies of $A$ and two copies of $B$?

Comment: No you don't have duplicate objects and yes objects are allowed to appear many times. Separate the notion of a diagram from its underlying category. Whilst a diagram in a category $\mathcal C$ can be represented formally as a factor $F: \mathcal D \to \mathcal C$ for some other category $\mathcal D$ It is better at this stage to view a diagram as an alternative way of assenting that certain arrows are equal to each other. In particular the diagram you have asserts that $f \circ 1_A = 1_B \circ f$.

Comment: Also your diagram has a typo $1_b \circ f$ should be $1_B \circ f$

Comment: @user2628206 fixed, thanks

Comment: $1_A$ respectively $1_B$ denotes the identity-morphism which exists in any category. In other words, given an object $A$ in your category $\mathcal{C}$, there's always a morphism $A\xrightarrow{1_A} A$ in $\mathcal{C}$

Comment: Typo in my original comment, Factor should be functor

Comment: What do you mean by the category described by a commutative diagram?

Comment: I don't think that this question has a clear meaning, tbh.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg To me, (the category described by a commutative diagram) translates as (the category whose objects and morphisms are shown in this commutative diagram). In what way is the question unclear? I feel like I'm punching through fog trying to pin down basic categorical ideas, so input is appreciated.

Comment: What does

"To me, (the category described by a commutative diagram) translates as (the category whose objects and morphisms are shown in this commutative diagram). "

mean? The parantheses are also somewhat confusingly placed. A category is not determined by commutative diagrams.

Comment: @Zest When I asked this question, I thought that a commutative diagram (noting that identity morphisms are not always drawn) determines a category, but apparently that is not the case.

Comment: @Mithrandir A category is the data of a set of objects and a set of morphisms for any couple of objects, with some axioms. Usually one deals with infinite categories and they tend to be hard to represent with finite diagrams. If one wants one can just draw a finite category defining it but it tends to get messy very quickly. For example if one would have wanted to do it for you diagram one could just write $A\to B$ because the identities are implicit. It is just the arrow category, and you can call it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one object $A$ and one object $B$. Yes, they are depicted twice in the diagram, but this does not mean that we have four distinct objects.

You can regard a commutative diagram as a collection of equations involving certain morphisms of the given category $\mathcal C$. Awodey's diagram does not use any individual properties of $\mathcal C$ or of the morphisms occurring in the diagram. Actually the diagram is completely tautological: The left triangle says that $f \circ 1_A = f \circ 1_A$ and the right triangle $1_B \circ f = 1_B \circ f$. A slightly more interesting diagram is obtained by replacing the "diagonal" arrows by $f$. This diagram says that  $f \circ 1_A = f$ and $1_B \circ f = f$, i.e. graphically depicts the defining property of *identity morphisms*. These two equations do not involve four distinct objects and five distinct morphisms, but only the two objects $A, B$ and the three morphisms $f, 1_A, 1_B$ between these two objects.

As a very simple analogue let us consider the equation
$$ 1 + 2 - 1 = 2 . \tag{1}$$
The integers $1, 2$ occur twice, but this does not mean that $(1)$ involves four distinct integers. There exist only one integer $1$ and one integer $2$, but both are multiply written in  $(1)$.

Let us now give a formal definition of a diagram.

A *diagram* in $\mathcal C$ consists of

1. A directed graph $\mathcal{G}$ with set of *vertices* $V$ and set of *edges* $E$ (note that an edge is nothing else than an ordered pair $(v,w)$ of vertices).
2. Functions $\phi_V  : V \to Ob(\mathcal C)$ from $V$ to the class of objects of $\mathcal C$ and $\phi_E  : E \to Mor(\mathcal C)$ from $E$ to the class of morphisms of $\mathcal C$ such that $\phi_E(v,w)$ is a morphism $\phi_V(v) \to \phi_V(w)$.

The diagram is *commutative* if for all finite paths in $\mathcal{G}$ connecting the same vertices $v, w$ the associated compositions of morphisms under $\phi_E$ yield the same morphism $\phi_V(v) \to \phi_V(w)$.

In Awodey's diagram the graph consists of four (distinct!) vertices and five (distinct!) edges. To these structure elements we associate two distinct objects and five distinct morphisms.

Comment: Thanks! Side-question: why restrict the definition of commutative to only finite paths?

Comment: @Mithrandir Diagrams may be infinite, and therefore may contain infinite paths, but it is impossible to define the composition of infinitely many morphisms. What would the codomain of such a composition?